Find the center of a circle from two Vector in Unity
I'd like to know if there's a formula for finding the center of a circle from two vectors.
For example, with a vector (2,4) and a vector (4,6), the position of the center would be a vector (4,4). Here's a picture of my problem.
In the image, we can see different vectors present on a circle and the aim of the formula would be to determine the coordinates of the green point from just two points.

I have try multiple code but no one works.
Some codes:
Vector3 direction = point1.forward.normalized;

        Vector3 centerApproximation = (point1.position + point2.position) / 2f;

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(point1.position, point2.position);

        Vector3 orthoVector = Vector3.Cross(direction, Vector3.up);

        Vector3 circleCenter = centerApproximation + orthoVector.normalized * Mathf.Sqrt((distance * distance) / 4 - Vector3.Dot(centerApproximation - point1.position, orthoVector.normalized));


        
        // Trouver le point médian
        Vector3 midpoint = (point1 + point2) / 2f;
        
        // Calculer un vecteur perpendiculaire à la droite formée par les deux points
        Vector3 direction = (point2 - point1).normalized;
        Vector3 perpendicular = new Vector3(-direction.z, 0, direction.x); // Pour un plan 2D, si besoin
        
        // Ajouter ce vecteur au point médian pour obtenir le troisième point
        Vector3 thirdPoint = midpoint + perpendicular * (distance / 2f);```


mathematically im sure there is, you need the normal from the point on the circle, through to the other side, and then you find where the lines intersect.. how? no idea never needed to do it

I think you will end up with multiple results, since the center could be in multiple places.  Take purple and black dots, imagine a circle that has those point on its boundary, with the center above and to the right.

There is an infinite number of circles passing through two points. If you knew the radius as well, you could narrow the number down to two. If you knew three points, you could calculate the center.

@beaker is correct, you could keep growing the circle endlessly and still have both points be on the edge of the circle, with the center point getting further from those points.

I think i can calculate the red point to get the diameter of the circle and find the purple point, i will try to do that. I'll keep you informed

In practice, I'd like the center of the circle to remain in the same direction as the point of origin.
For example, for the blue point (2,4), which would have a direction (1,0), the center of the circle could be on the (X,4) coordinates only.

If you want just any circle .. well your first approach is already var center = (A + B) / 2f; var radius = (A - B).magnitude / 2f .. that's the smallest circle passing through both positions...

I finally found a solution.
It's probably not the best, but it'll do for now.
For the first point, I'm using a Transform rather than a vector to give a desired direction for the center of the circle.
From the line formed by the direction, I find a third vector which is the symmetry between the second vector and the line.
Then, using these three vectors, I calculate the position of the center of the circle.
Here's the draft code that does it:
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform transform1;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 position2;


    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (transform1 == null || position2 == null)
            return;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform1.position, 0.1f);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform1.position, transform1.position + transform1.forward * 10f);

        Gizmos.DrawSphere(position2, 0.1f);

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(GetSymetricPosition(transform1, position2), 0.1f);

        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(GetCenterOfCircle(transform1.position, position2, GetSymetricPosition(transform1, position2)), 0.1f);
    }

    private Vector3 GetCenterOfCircle(Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2, Vector3 point3)
    {
        float x1 = point1.x;
        float x2 = point2.x;
        float x3 = point3.x;
        float y1 = point1.z;
        float y2 = point2.z;
        float y3 = point3.z;

        float x12 = x1 - x2;
        float x13 = x1 - x3;

        float y12 = y1 - y2;
        float y13 = y1 - y3;

        float y31 = y3 - y1;
        float y21 = y2 - y1;

        float x31 = x3 - x1;
        float x21 = x2 - x1;

        float sx13 = x1 * x1 - x3 * x3;
        float sy13 = y1 * y1 - y3 * y3;

        float sx21 = x2 * x2 - x1 * x1;
        float sy21 = y2 * y2 - y1 * y1;

        float f = ((sx13) * (x12) + (sy13) * (x12) + (sx21) * (x13) + (sy21) * (x13)) / (2 * ((y31) * (x12) - (y21) * (x13)));
        float g = ((sx13) * (y12) + (sy13) * (y12) + (sx21) * (y13) + (sy21) * (y13)) / (2 * ((x31) * (y12) - (x21) * (y13)));

        float c = -x1 * x1 - y1 * y1 - 2 * g * x1 - 2 * f * y1;

        float h = -g;
        float k = -f;
        float sqr_of_r = h * h + k * k - c;

        float r = Mathf.Sqrt(sqr_of_r);

        Vector3 center = new Vector3(h, 0, k);
        return center;
    }

    private Vector3 GetSymetricPosition(Transform transform1, Vector3 position2)
    {
        Vector3 direction = transform1.forward;
        Vector3 intersectDirection = transform1.position + direction * Vector3.Dot(position2 - transform1.position, direction);
        return intersectDirection + (intersectDirection - position2);
    }
}```

